# How to individually style form elements with CSS (no javascript)

Tags: css, forms

I am editing a module on a website for event registrations. It has a CSS entry that controls a form. The entry is simply

```
#component .component_form input {border:1px solid #ccc; padding:3px;}
```

What I need to do is group form elements and style some of them individually. So you can imagine a form that has sections like Contact Info, Work Info, etc. In the form, these sections would be blocks, where the top of the block would have the section title, and then each element would have size defined by the class, but also some elements would have to be different from others in the class. Conceptually, I think this will involve creating classes and ids. Maybe something like this?

```
  #component .component_form .contact_info input {properties}
  #component .component_form .contact_info #firstname input {properties}
```

etc

Am I on the right track?

Then would I do something like this?

```
<div class = "contact_info">
<input class = "contact_info" id = "firstname"...></input>
<input class = "contact_info" ...></input>
...
</div>
```

The thing that confuses me about CSS is when you have these existing cascading relationships and knowing how to properly create new classes/ids and fit them in the existing cascade and then select them properly in the html.

And while I know people say separate style and content, I would like to even have the CSS specify a title for each group (Contact Info, etc). Maybe doing something like this?

```
#component .component_form .contact_info div:before {
  content: "Contact Info";
}
```

What do you think? I am trying to do this like pros would!

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML structure?

Comment: Yes, I have total flexibility to edit the CSS and HTML but am trying to do as much in CSS. And what I forgot to mention, the elements I am trying to edit are already nested in other divs that have existing classes/ids... So it is really confusing how to specify the selection in CSS.

Comment: Well, if you prefer not to touch the HTML structure we need the exact structure to give you a specific answer. Otherwise a given solution might be overwritten by another piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more details. It would take up a lot of space to show the structure, but you can see this form as I am editing it:

http://dev.pfp-consortium.org/index.php/events/1-regional-stability-in-the-south-caucasus-workshop/registration

You can see what I mean about a profusion of existing classes, ids. I did notice that the following: allows me to style individual elements:

```
input#field {width:50px}
```

Where #field is already defined by the event registration component that I am editing. So I guess it is a matter of figuring out how to define the classes for the registration form groups and then select the classes/existing ids.